# Why Task[from metadata] does not list public property CompletedTask?

Tags: c#

I use VS2017/C# with NET Framework Version 4.7.03056. The command Go To Definition run on class `Task` takes me to Task[from metadata] in mscorlib 4.0.0.0. The source code as shown on referencesource.microsoft.com lists class `Task` with public property:

```
public static Task CompletedTask
```

but Task[from metadata] does not show it even though it is public, meaning that I cannot call it from my code. Why is it missing?

Comment: Show me screenshot

Comment: What is your target framework version?

Comment: It is the default 4.5.2

Comment: @LolitaGherp 4.5.2 is not in the list: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask#applies-to